# Laravel post data with $.post

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to set up ajax for laravel, but it won't work. I have controller for check validation and update from database. javascript which blocks the submit form do not work and page is refresh.

do not work means: `alert('SUBMIT');` into submit form not work and alert me without any error and warning.

i test `alert('SUBMIT');` but that does not work. but `alert('ACTION');` correct and alert me.

my included correct JS:

```
<head>
    <title>Alachiq</title>
    <meta charset='UTF-8' />

    {{HTML::script('js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js')}}

</head>
```

jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

       alert('ACTION');//

       $('#submit').click(function(){

       alert('SUBMIT');

       name         = $('#name').val();
       family       = $('#family').val();
       email        = $('#email').val();
       currPassword = $('#currPassword').val();
       password     = $('#password').val();
       password_confirmation = $('#password_confirmation').val();     

       $.post("{{ URL::route('admin.profile.update') }}",
            { 
              name                  : name,
              family                : family,
              email                 : email,
              currPassword          : currPassword,
              password              : password,
              password_confirmation : password_confirmation  
            },
            function()
            {
                alert('sss');
            },'json');
       });
});
</script>
```

my sample of form:

```
{{ Form::model($profile, array('route' => array('admin.profile.update', $profile->id), 'method' => 'PUT')) }}

...

{{ Form::close() }}
```

my simple controller

```
public function update($id)
{
  if ( Request::ajax() ){
             return Response::json(array(
                    'errors'=>'ddddd'
                ));
  }
}
```

UPDATE:
my route:

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function()
{

  Route::get  ('admin/contents', array('as'=>'contents', function(){
      return View::make('back_end.layouts.contents');
  }));
  Route::resource  ('admin/profile' , 'ProfileController'          , array('as'=>'profile', 'before'=>'csrf'));

  Route::get('admin/createNewContents' ,array('as'=>'createNew', function(){
      return View::make('back_end.layouts.createNewContents');
  }));
});
```

Comment: Check for errors in the browser's console.

Comment: Could you also try `$("form").submit(function(event) {...})` rather than `$("#submit").click(function() {...})`? Remember to call `event.preventDefault()`

Comment: @SheikhHeera hi SheikhHeera please help me. i tired today. in firebug console i do not have any problem,warning :(

Comment: Try `matpop`'s suggestion.

Comment: @SheikhHeera  `matpop` ?? whats this?

Comment: Use `event.preventDefault()`, you got an answer, follow this.

Comment: @SheikhHeera using ` event.preventDefault();` after `document.ready` not any change. i have problem.

Comment: Can yo add an id to your form ?

Comment: Wow, I became a piece of code!

Comment: @matpop, yes, I recommended it, so what about me ?

Comment: @SheikhHeera  i change `$('form')` to `$('#submit')`. submit button: `{{ Form::submit('SUBMIT BUTTON', array('id'=>'submit')) }}`. but not any change

Comment: If you're tryng jQuery `.submit()` now, you must call it on the form, not on the submit button

Comment: @matpop  i try your tips such as `$('form').submit`but does not work.

Comment: @SheikhHeera can you help me? please i'm tired

Comment: @TuxWorld, did you check the answer ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
{{ Form::model($profile, array('route' => array('admin.profile.update', $profile->id), 'method' => 'PUT', 'id' => 'frm')) }}

{{ Form::close() }}
```

Notice the `'id' => 'frm'` in the form `model` after `'method' => 'PUT'`. Now use following code to submit the form

```
$('#frm').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    // rest of your code
});
```

**Update:** Change the route declaration to this (Also add `_method:"PUT"` in your post data):

<strike>Route::group(array('prefix'=> 'admin', 'before' => 'csrf'), function(){</strike>

```
Route::resource('/profile' , 'ProfileController');
```

<strike>});</strike>

Now from `command prompt/terminal` run `php artisan routes` command and check each routes (url and name) to find out what is the right route for this action `Laravel` used.

**Update:** Add this in your `ProfileController` controller

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->beforeFilter('csrf', array('on' => array('post', 'delete', 'put', 'patch')));
}
```

Comment: thanks. i get this error now `POST http://localhost/alachiq/public/admin/profile/%7Bprofile%7D 404 Not Found`. i'm change original post and instered my route.

Comment: Pass the parameter to `$.post("{{ route('admin.profile.update', $profile->id) }}"`.

Comment: @SheikhHeera Why the hell didn't it fire with $('form')?

Comment: @matpop, He probably made mistake.

Comment: @TuxWorld, did you get it ?

Comment: @SheikhHeera  yeah i get error: `POST http://localhost/alachiq/public/admin/profile/1   404 Not Found`. if i do not use Ajax this URL is correct

Comment: Why `public` is in the your `url` ?

Comment: @SheikhHeera this is default for laravel and i do not chage that or inserted that.

Comment: @TuxWorld According to your form you should do a PUT, not a POST. Or, at least, add a `_method: "PUT"` parameter.

Comment: What is your `url` for this, what you use to navigate to this page without `ajax` ?

Comment: @SheikhHeera  url is `http://localhost/alachiq/public/admin/profile` and without use or disable ajax that work correctly and i do not have any problem. i tested now.

Comment: @matpop this is your mean? `'method' => 'PUT'` or hidden atrribute?

Comment: Nope. I mean in the js. You're doing a `.post()`

Comment: @matpop  i do not never use it. how to change js code ?

Comment: What is your `route` for this in `routes.php` ?

Comment: Let's try a quick fix: add `_method: "PUT"` in the post data

Comment: `'method' => 'PUT'` is available in the `Form::model()` so `Laravel` will add it.

Comment: @SheikhHeera i pasted `route` on end of original post.

Comment: @TuxWorld yeah but not in the js!

Comment: @SheikhHeera can you find my problem?

Comment: @TuxWorld did you try to add that js line?? Maybe a chat would have been better... or a little rest

Comment: @TuxWorld, you can't use `Route::resource  ('admin/profile' , 'ProfileController'          , array('as'=>'profile', 'before'=>'csrf'));` it wont work, check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21584317/741747).

Comment: @SheikhHeera ok. how to change that to controller? `Route::controller  ('admin/profile' , 'ProfileController');` not correct and laravel could not find /admin/profile link.

Comment: Check the updated answer, keep it inside `group` and leave it as it's `resource`.

Comment: @SheikhHeera thanks.after change to that i get this error now: `Illuminate \ Session \ TokenMismatchException` in `/var/www/alachiq/app/filters.php` file

Comment: Add this in your `csrf` filter at the top `if($request->getMethod() == "GET") return;`. `Route::filter('csrf', function($r, $request) { if($request->getMethod() == "GET") return; // ... });`

Comment: For more help on this topic, [check this link](https://www.google.com.bd/search?q=laravel+Illuminate+%5C+Session+%5C+TokenMismatchException&rlz=1C1KMZB_enBD539BD539&oq=laravel+Illuminate+%5C+Session+%5C+TokenMismatchException&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l5.1942j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8).

Comment: @SheikhHeera after change `Route` and add `__construct()` to Controller. i get error : `POST http://localhost/alachiq/public/admin/profile/1 404 Not Found`. link to `$.post` is `$.post("{{ route('admin.profile.update', $profile->id) }}",` i have this problen in Ajax action :(

Comment: @matpop  after inserting `_method: "PUT"` in the post of data, my problem solved

Comment: I'm sexy and I know it! Well, when using `Form::open` or `Form::model`, you should also include the automatically added CSRF `_token` hidden value with your AJAX call data. At last, in such a scenario, it is more practical to jQuery `.serialize()` the form data. Also, please note that our chat-like style in this question is of little use for the others. Next time let's open a real chat room rather than posting.